# Adding Javascript to Header in React-Admin App

Tags: react-admin

I'd like to add a dynamic javascript script to every page's `<head>` in a react-admin app, but not sure the best way/place to do this. I've seen a lot with React-Helmet, but feel like this should be simpler than having to import something else.

I can accomplish 95% of what I'm looking to do by adding it to an HTML template that I use, but I need to inject a user id in it so needs to be on the javascript side. No code included, but looking for general guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your upmost react-admin file, generally just before the `<Admin/>` component, you can have a `useEffect` to add the script to head.

example:

```
const App = () => {

  // Hooks are called before the return statement on mount on unmount.
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script')
    // You create your script here, usually by script.src = `https://${process.env.YOUR_URL_ID}`

    document.head.appendChild(script)

    // To delete the script on unmount
    return () => {
      document.head.removeChild(script)
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <Admin>All of the Stuff</Admin>
  )
}
export default App
```

Comment: So this is set up like so ```const App = () => (<Admin>All of the Stuff</Admin); export default App;
``` and attempting to drop your code anywhere creates an invalid hook. Sorry not great with React but trying to feel my way through this one.

Comment: I edited my answer in order to have a clearer view. Hooks are called between App declaration and its return.